# Can I see a detailed list where my resources are being used?

Tags: civilization-5

So according to my resources on the top bar, I can make 20 aluminum. The problem is that I'm using 17 of it which doesn't leave me with a lot.

Is there anywhere I can go to see a detailed breakdown that explains what things are using some of this aluminum, so that I can get rid of them and free up some more for Rocket Artillery?

(I have all the DLC)

Comment: Been a bit since I played, but can you click on the aluminum meter to see?

Comment: @zpletan Nope, it doesn't appear so. I can see how much is being used versus how much I have, but I cant seem to find anywhere I can see where the resource is being used.

Answer (score 2):

No there does not seem to be a single screen where you can see where your resources are being used - unless you download a mod from the steam workshop.

Without modding you will need to look in a couple of places
- the unit list under the military overview on the left hand side drop down menu to see which resources are used by your units
- The economic details screen where you can see which resources are being traded with other nations.
- I couldn't find a better way to see how many resources are used by buildings than visiting each city screen, and even then you have to know which buildings use which resource because it doesn't tell you. You can look up each building in the civilopedia on the top right menu but looking up the resource does not tell you what buildings or units use it.